# App is not opening in Android 5.1 and lower version devices

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I created an app using android studio. Uploaded to play store. Its working fine in all devices except android version 5.1 and lower version devices. The app is not even opening in those devices.
I have tried my best to solve this problem but I failed.
.
So, please tell me guys how to solve it??
.
In stack trace it is showing : 
.
Caused by : android.view.inflateException
.
At packageName.splash.oncreate (Splash.java:23)
.
Here Splash.java is my splash screen activity...

Here is my Splash.java code :

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setupWindowAnimations();
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textviewmain);
        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textviewmain2);
        ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.logo_s);
        Animation animation1 =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
        logo.startAnimation(animation1);
        textView.startAnimation(animation1);
        textView1.startAnimation(animation1);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    super.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }





        };
        timer.start();
    }
    private void setupWindowAnimations() {
       Fade fade = new Fade();
        fade.setDuration(3000);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
    }
}
```

and activity_splash.xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#092865"
    tools:context=".Splash"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splashbg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-315dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splashbg2"

            />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidesplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_s"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:contentDescription="@string/daily_highlights_dose"
            android:src="@drawable/icon24"
            android:transitionName="logo" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewmain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/logo_s"
            android:text="@string/sports"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewmain2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textviewmain"
            android:text="Highlights"
            android:textColor="#1FD883"
            android:textSize="27sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 <!-- #f93959  -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If it fails to open, it'll produce a stack trace. Nothing to do without one of those.

Comment: How to check and find that stack trace. @Matt_Clark

Comment: You should share logs and what you did to generate your app. Your question is too vague and it's very hard for someone else helping you!

Comment: Sorrry, Sir i am a beginner... I generated a signed bundle of my app...uploade it to play store.... API level 21...  I don't know how to check log in a smartphone???... In android studio I can check the log... but I don't think that it will show anything because the problem is occurring only in some versions... & its working fine with other versions...

Comment: In stack trace it is showing : 
.
Caused by : android.view.inflateException
.
At packageName.splash.oncreate (Splash.java:23)
.
Here Splash.java is my splash screen activity...

Comment: Sharing your SplashScreen code might help the others on helping you, mind doing that please? :)

Comment: Instead of just mentioning one line of error, it is good to post full error log and code of file which causing the issue. So someone can help you easily.

Comment: I have edited the question with code please check it sir...  @DHAVALASODARIYA

Comment: Yes, I have seen, now what about the full crash log?

Comment: how to find that @DHAVALASODARIYA

Comment: From there where you had find this line. -> Caused by : android.view.inflateException . At packageName.splash.oncreate (Splash.java:23) It's in `logcat`.

Comment: I found it on Google Play console crash report  @DHAVALASODARIYA

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is ocuuring just because of size of images, 
                    You should check your image size which are put in splash Activity
                    or replace those images by others and then check it

Comment: Its 991×991 for first image i.e. for image with id splashbg... and 512x512 for other